# How do I avoid Windows abbreviating the account when setting which user a Service should Log On As?

Tags: sql-server, windows, service

I am trying to set a Windows Service to "Log On" as a specific Windows user, using the Windows GUI. This should allow the service to authenticate as that user when connecting to Microsoft SQL Server.

However, when I provide the account name in this format `<DOMAIN NAME>\<username>` and click "Apply", the account name gets abbreviated as `.\<username>`.

As a result, it seems that the service is unable to authenticate with SQL Server, since SQL Server doesn't have a user with the name `.\<username>`. SQL Server expects the name to be `<DOMAIN NAME>\<username>`.

Is there a way to prevent the account name from being abbreviated like this?

Comment: domain\user is the old style "pre windows 2000" format, have you tried using username@domain fqdn style?

Comment: I have tried "username@domain", "username@domain.com", "username@domain.org", and "username@domain.local". Each returns the following error: "The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted."

Comment: By "domain name" do you machine "computer name"? It sounds like this computer is in a workgroup instead of joined to an Active Directory domain. A service account getting saved with `.\username` is typically an account local to the current computer via Local User Manager (lusrmgr.msc).

Comment: You're right -- it looks like what I've thought was the domain name is actually the computer name. I've confirmed this by logging into the computer as `.\<username>`. 

However, I haven't yet solved my problem -- which is that SQL Server expects the Windows user that I'm logging in as to be named `<computer name>/<username>`, whereas my service "Logs On" as `./<computer name>`. And unfortunately the database I'm connecting to is read-only, so I can't change the user's name on SQL Server...

Comment: I should note that I _have_ been able to connect to SQL Server as `<computer name>/<username>` using SQL Server Studio, and via bcp in a bash script. So I feel like it should be possible for my Service to connect as well...